# How "for (_, value) in kwargs.items():" works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In most case, we use `for key, value in dict.items()`, but `for [_, value] in kwargs.items():` also works.
How Python interprets those codes?

I accidently found the following function didn't report an error:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum += i

    for [_, value] in kwargs.items():
        sum += value
        print(kwargs.items())

    return sum
```

I checked the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) of dict but stayed confused.

Comment: Are you asking about the `_` or about the `[ ]`? Your title says `(_, value)` which is not even in the code you posted.

Comment: See (1) the definition of `for` which includes a "target_list" element: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement (2) the definition of the target_list, which states *"a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets,"* https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements So the syntax allows you to have `for _, value` or `for (_, value)` or `for [_, value]` with the same meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In most case, we use for key, value in dict.items(), but for [_, value] in kwargs.items(): also works. How Python interprets those codes?

Exactly the same way?

`_` is a valid Python identifier, it's used to mean "don't care" (unnecessarily as `dict.values()` exists) inherited from functional languages. Functional languages often special-case it (as a write-only binding), but Python does not even do that:

```
_ = 1
print(_)
```

will print 1, although beware that the Python console will implicitly set `_` to the result of the last expression evaluated:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> print(_)
3
```

And in target position (left-hand side) there's *essentially* no difference between a list (`[]`) and a tuple (`()`, the parens are optional / implicit here) as targets: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

All that happens is that the value (the right hand side, of each iteration since this is a loop) gets iterated, and each value gets assigned to one of the targets from left to right.

You can [disassemble](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) the two statements to see exactly how Python interprets them:

```
>>> dis.dis('for key, value in dict.items(): pass')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (items)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 18)
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (key)
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (value)
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('for [_, value] in kwargs.items(): pass')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (kwargs)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (items)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 18)
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (_)
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (value)
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Aside from the `LOAD_NAME` at offset 0 (because the source object has a different name) and the `STORE_NAME` at offset 12 (because one of the targets has a different name), they're identical.